# Integration code editor with React Native App

Tags: react-native, expo, ace-editor, monaco-editor

I'd like to add a code editor to my React Native app, but I have not found a code editor for this.  Ace Editor and Monaco works only with react but not with react native. Does React Native or Expo SDK support Ace or Monaco?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking for suggestions for a code editor package that will work in a React Native application, out of the box.

To answer your question directly: no, `monaco-editor`, `ace` and `Codemirror` do **not** explicitly support React Native.

With that said, it is certainly possible to integrate those editors into a React Native application using a wrapper and/or additional hacks to handle edge cases.  [This user has integrated monaco](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1365) in RN apps but has not provided example code.

Comment: but do you have any idea how can i integrate monaco like this user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to integrate javascript code editor in to your reactnative application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-monacco-editor

Comment: ... ideally you'd show _how_ to use it. Not just link to it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).